# Flutter GetX refresh page after Get.back()

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have controller with a lot of variables. Variables are shows on 1st page. Then I go to 2nd page where values are edited. After that I go back using Material Design button back or Android system button back to 1st page, but values are not refreshed and view values are not equal with values from controller.

How to solve this problem and force check and refresh values from controller on every back()? Important is that I have a lot of sources with command back - systems button, material design navigators and some other widgets like buttons with text "Save and close".

Comment: Would you please include a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so other users are able to identify the problem.

Comment: I think you can use .then method to refresh the, you can simply call onInit function in this method.  For ex: Get.to(NextScreen()).then((value) {
      //TODO call onInit() to refresh page
    });